# Multi page, float16 image viewer

Tags: floating-point, image-viewer

Looking for some utility to easily view multipage tiff files, which can display float16/uint16 data, and be able to easy to display next image in directory.
On windows I was using Irfanview for it.

I try a couple of programs, but none of it was able to tick all 3 requirements.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. There is another SE (Stack Exchange) platform geared towards people looking for software recommendations. Check it out at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. They might be able to assist you.

Comment: thanks for suggestion